# Different order from the expected

Tags: c

I need to print the permutation in the order, for example, abc must be (abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba), but my program does it differently. It is printing cba before cab, which is not what I wanted; what can I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void troca(char *x, char *y){
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}


void jeitos(char *a, int f, int h){

  int i;

  if (f == h){
    printf("%s\n", a);
  }
  else{
    for (i = f; i <= h; i++){
      troca((a + f), (a + i));
      jeitos(a, f + 1, h);
      troca((a + f), (a + i)); 
    } 
  }
}

int main(){
    
  char string[6];
  scanf("%s", string);
  int n = strlen(string);
  jeitos(string, 0, n-1);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the input were "acb", would the desired output be the same as you've shown (sorted alphabetically)?

Comment: What is the logic of the desired output?

Comment: What do you expect from input "zaW" ? In other words - what is the meaning of "in the order"? Sorted strings or ...?

Comment: OT: Use english function names. Sooner or later, you need to show the code to someone that doesn't understand "jeitos". It could be on stack overflow

Comment: yes @jarmod, i wanted it sorted alphabetically

Comment: yes @500-InternalServerError thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928236/print-all-permutation-in-lexicographic-order/57528309#57528309 Does this answer your question?